# Include condition inside javascript in relation php constant

Tags: javascript, php

i would know how to include a condition inside js. Like you can see in my table I this constant MODE_B2B_B2C; 
How to make the same thing inside js.

Tk.

```
         <table width="100%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0">
           <tr>
        if (MODE_B2B_B2C == 'true') {
          $content .= '
                          <td>' . $this->app->getDef('table_heading_customers_group') . '</td>
                      ';
        }
</tr>
</table>

      $output = <<<EOD
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
  var quantitydiscount_row = $i;

  function addQuantityDiscountValue() {


   //customers_group_id
    html += '<td>';
    html += '  <select name="products_quantitydiscount[' + quantitydiscount_row + '][customers_group_id]" class="form-control">{$customers_group_name}</select>';
    html += '</td>';


    quantitydiscount_row++;
  }
</script>
<br />
EOD;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Template Strings:

```js
let myVal = 123;
function condition(input) {
  if (input > 10) return "foo";
  return "bar";
}


let str = `This will output ${myVal} * 2 = ${myVal * 2}. 
Condition: ${condition(2)}
Condition: ${condition(20)}
`;

console.log(str);
```

Comment: Sorry on't follow you